# How do I map a local directory to a Docker's container's directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to map several configuration files located in my local **App_Data** and **Themes** to the same folders inside a Docker container. The goal is to ensure the container is using the same configuration as my development machine and allow me to modify and test themes without rebuilding the container.

I am modifying an existing script, but I get the following error message with no indication of the offending line:

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not an array.
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

The existing script goes through a long build process which involves a long build process, but I would like this script to work on a prebuilt container. Can I simply remove the build step?

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  nopcommerce_web:
    image: nopcommerce:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - nopcommerce_database
    volumes:
      - /src/Presentation/Nop.Web/App_Data
  nopcommerce_database:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: nopcommerce_mssql_server
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "nopCommerce_db_password"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
```

Finally, is there an interactive tool for configuring Docker?

Comment: The top-level `volumes:` block at the very end of the file is unused and you can delete it in its entirety.  The syntax complaint is that the `nopcommerce_data:` line can't have a YAML list marker `-` at the start of the line.

Comment: I updated the script to the latest. It runs, but still doesn't do what I want it to do.

Comment: YAML is aweful!  Too cryptic to be of any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes
You would want something like:

```
services:
  nopcommerce_web:
    image: nopcommerce:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - nopcommerce_database
    volumes:
      - /src/Presentation/Nop.Web/App_Data:/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/App_Data
```

Presuming that you want to mount your host and docker container paths the same.

Comment: Thanks Terry!  Will this override the existing App_Data path on the container? I want the container to ignore its App_Data and mount to this location instead?  In essence, I want to establish a hard link to my local App_Data.

Comment: It will overlay the contents of the container directory, but the host volume data will take precedence. When using volumes in my experience it's usually best to bind it to an empty directory. If you need to you clean empty the contents of your container directory during the build process.